# Android, How to launch Activity over Lock screen

Tags: android

I want launch my activity on push notification over lock screen without change in lock.

Any special permission for that activity?

Comment: have you any example app that work as like you say?

Comment: Hangouts does this

Comment: wechat also does this when receive call, app show up even if phone is sleep and lock

Answer (score 33):

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1)
    {
        setShowWhenLocked(true);
        setTurnScreenOn(true);
        KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        if(keyguardManager!=null)
            keyguardManager.requestDismissKeyguard(this, null);
    }
    else 
    {
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD |
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
    }
```

Comment: Actually, this code looks like the best and version-aware solution. should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Where should this code go? I had it in onCreate, but when I turn the screen off, the onCreate method is never called, so this code is never run.

Comment: @trampster This code simply sets flags for your app. These describe how the app should behave when phone is locked. The code is not supposed to run on lock/unlock.

Comment: why we need  `keyguardManager.requestDismissKeyguard(this, null);` ? it actually causes memory leak

Comment: @beginner The Keyguard deals with unlocking the phone and will prompt you to input a PIN or pattern, whatever security measure you have. When you display info on a locked screen - it is your choice if you want that or not. About the method itself, here is a description at android.com: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager#requestDismissKeyguard(android.app.Activity,%20android.app.KeyguardManager.KeyguardDismissCallback)

Comment: @VladimirDemirev can you please confirm if this works on Android 8 in this scenario: App is turned on, then phone is locked, then does it wake up to show on top of lockscreen? For me it doesn't wakeup on push when I turn on the app. In Android 10 this code will work.

Comment: @Waleed I do have the same issue. I start my activity in a service (which is triggered from push). The think is, that my Pixel phone will wake up, but not my Samsung A20. We tested 4 Android devices and on 2 it's working and the other don't react. Did you fix your problem?

Answer (score 9):

After API level 17 this would work

```
<activity
    android:name=".yourActivityName"
    android:showOnLockScreen="true"
    android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait" >
```

or write this in onCreate() before calling `setContentView()`

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
```

Comment: While Clicking on Notification, lock screen dialog shown. Not working on my phone.

Comment: @Ravi can you please confirm if this works on Android 8 in this scenario: App is turned on, then phone is locked, then does it wake up to show on top of lockscreen? For me it doesn't wakeup on push when I turn on the app. In Android 10 this code will work.

Comment: `android:showOnLockScreen` is deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

The other answers include extra functionality that you may or may not want.

The minimum code to allow your activity to display on the lock screen is this:

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 27)
        setShowWhenLocked(true);
    else
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);

    // setContentView etc
}
```

If you also want your activity to turn on the screen  (since it might be off) or unlock the keyguard, then see [Vladimir Demirev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55998126/238753).

Comment: can you please confirm if this works on Android 8 in this scenario: App is turned on, then phone is locked, then does it wake up to show on top of lockscreen?

Comment: You code will be more readable if you use a constant for the build number instead of a hardcoded value such as 27.

Answer (score 3):

In the method onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) you should add some window flags:

```
Window window = this.getWindow();
window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

Answer (score 1):

To show your activity over lock screen:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
        setShowWhenLocked(true)
        setTurnScreenOn(true)
    } else {
        window.addFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
            or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
        )
    }

    setContentView(binding.root)
    ...
}
```

Please note that Xiaomi requires additional permission from the manufacturer.
You can read about this issue here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52590297/11980977

Additionaly, if you want to request unlock keyguard and perform action when keyguard unlocked:

```
private fun handleButtonClickWhenLocked(clickAction: () -> Unit) {
    val keyguardManager = getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE) as KeyguardManager
    if (!keyguardManager.isKeyguardLocked) {
        clickAction.invoke()
    } else {
        val keyguardDismissCallback = object : KeyguardManager.KeyguardDismissCallback() {

             override fun onDismissSucceeded() {
                 clickAction.invoke()
             }
         }
         keyguardManager.requestDismissKeyguard(this, keyguardDismissCallback)
    }
}
```