# Is there anyway to unlock lockscreen with pattern/password programmatically in Android Marshmallow?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, lockscreen

Like TrueCaller, at incoming call.

When I've get an incoming call, TrueCaller show a dialog over the dialer app even if my phone is lock.

The problem in Android Marshmallow only.

I am using this code in the activity at onCreate method:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD)
```

Comment: Do you find any solution? Do you try smartlock option in android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Camilo Ortegón in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35356848/android-how-to-launch-activity-over-lock-screen)

In onCreate, before setContectView(), add this lines:

```
Window window = this.getWindow();
window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

Finally:

```
class MyActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /***THE MAGIC***/
        Window window = this.getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
        /*** ***/

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);
     }
}
```