# Run service before Android device screen unlock

Tags: android, service, unlock

I'm working on a calling feature app and app need to open certain activity after getting push notification. In order to open an activity I need some authentication which implemented in a service. I'm getting the push and after authentication successfully it start the activity but system destroy the service because Android screen still unlock(Everything works well when app is not locked). I needs the following things:

- Need to keep service alive
  or
- Unlock the phone programmatically.

Looking for some help.

Comment: Running into the same problem, try direct boot mode
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#receive_fcm_messages_in_direct_boot_mode

Comment: Looks like you can't bypass the phone lock programtically, but I found a way to display the activity before phone is unlock, https://stackoverflow.com/a/55998126/5777189