# Launch activity for income call when phone is locked android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest, incoming-call

I want to launch an incoming call activity when the device screen is locked in Android.
I have added to my manifest the following

```
<activity
            android:name=".ui.activities.incomingcall.IncomingCallActivity"
            android:showOnLockScreen="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:theme="@style/NoActionBar" />
```

So when i receive a new message from Firebase i execute a piece of code that starts an Intent and rise a notification with fullPendingIntent to open that activity.
However, that does not work properly
What can i do? Is there any Alarm Broadcast receiver that i should use which can do such thing?

Answer (score 1):

Use a high-priority notification with a full-screen intent. In case of the device is locked you can send full-screen intent otherwise display a heads-up notification when the device is not locked.

Comment: Well i have already done that. The trick is this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55998126/5371749
I put this in my onCreate call and now it open the activity