# Android studio: how to unlock screen and go to an activity when alarm triggers

Tags: android, android-studio

Is there any way that I can use `BroadcastReceiver.onReceive` in order to unlock the screen (if the screen is locked) and start the app on a given activity, e.g. `FirstActivity`?

Comment: I don't think apps can unlock a device, that would cause a back door and thus a security problem. Usually if you want to show something you have to bring your activity before the lock screen. In that way the phone would remain locked but your activity is accessible.

Comment: that would work as well. How can I achieve that?

Comment: May be use a search engine to find an answer like this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35356848/150978